# Count unique rows of 3 join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I would like to count several items in the 3 tables:

- "Total" - The total Serialnumbers in a batch (Batch is the 3 first digits of Serialnumber)
- "Call_Per_Code" - Count the unique codes with a callnr for each batch
- "NoCall" - Count the unique codes without a callnr for each batch

Sample data below:

```
Table Test1
CallNr      CallType  
1           rej  
2           rej  
3           rej  
4           rej  
5           QC  
6           QC  
7           rej  
8           rej  

Table Test2
CallNr     Code  
1          201401  
3          201402  
4          201404  
5          201401  
7          201401  
8          201401

Table Test3  
Code    PartCode  SerialNumber  
201401  68001     123-01  
201402  68001     123-02  
201403  68001     123-03  
201404  68001     124-01  
201405  68001     124-02  
201406  68001     124-03
```

The result must be:

```
Batch Total NoCall Call_Per_Code  
123   3     1      2  
124   3     2      1
```

But I get the result:

```
Batch Total NoCall Call_Per_Code  
123   3     1      4  
124   2     1      1
```

I am using the sql code on a SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT
   substring(T3.SerialNumber,1,3) as batch
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT concat(T3.code,substring(T3.SerialNumber,1,3))) as Total
   ,sum(case when T2.CallNr is null then 1 else 0 end) as NoCall
   ,sum(case when T2.CallNr is null then 0 else 1 end) as Call_per_Code
FROM Test1 T1 
    INNER JOIN Test2 T2 
        ON T1.CallNr=T2.CallNr AND T1.CallType='rej' 
    RIGHT JOIN Test3 T3 
        ON T2.Code=T3.Code  
GROUP BY substring(T3.SerialNumber,1,3)
```

How can I get the correct count on the column Call_Per_Code. The Code 201401 with a CallNr is count as 3 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets a lot easier if you start from Test3 - you don't even need to join to Test1 if you start from there:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(T3.SerialNumber, 1, 3) AS Batch,
   COUNT(DISTINCT T3.Code) AS Total,
   SUM(CASE WHEN T2.CallNr IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoCall,
   COUNT(DISTINCT T2.Code) AS Call_Per_Code
FROM Test3 T3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Test2 T2 ON T3.Code = T2.Code
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(T3.SerialNumber, 1, 3)
```